# IBM Mainframe blocked "X NOT HERE"

Tags: input, cursor, mainframe, blocked

When make an entry not in the enabled places on the screen, Mainframe gets blocked with the error message "X NOT HERE" and requires a `reset`.
Is there any setting which removes the need for blocking?
Thanks
P.
[IBM Mainframe error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpyFB.png)

[image]

Comment: What interface are you using? Can you show a more compete picture?

Comment: Are you asking how to reset the screen, or how to prevent the blocking from happening in the first place?  The first is easy; the latter would be possible, I suppose, but very difficult.

Comment: More information than the picture you are providing is needed.  What emulator are you using?  Is this a TN3270 connection or a local terminal.  If you can provide a screen shot of what you're trying to access that doesn't divulge private or proprietary information it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

3270 is a block oriented interface that allows the programmer to define fields that are transferred to the mainframe when a key called an Attention Identifer (AID) is pressed.  This can be an `enter`, `pa1`, `clear` or other AID type.

As such, the screen is presented with content that includes Text as well as fields.  Like a browser presents data as text and also allows for data entry fields.  Like a browser, you cannot type in a read-only area.   Only in areas that are defined for input.

As such, this really depends on the application you are using.  TSO generally is presented using a program called `ISPF` which uses 3270 to present information.  Some is read-only, others are read-write.

There is no way to generically do "unblocking" as it is based on what the application is presenting.  What you mention as "restart" I think is really the `reset` key.

Another reference that would be useful for IBM's emulator is [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/personal-communications/5.9?topic=reference-key-functions-keyboard-setup).

For more information on programming 3270 devices I would refer to this [page](http://www.prycroft6.com.au/misc/3270.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. The application used is BlueZone.

Answer (score 0):

In the same time I have found the solution I was looking for. In BlueZone: Options -> Keyboard -> Options (again) -> Auto-Reset when Keyboard is locked.
Thanks a lot all.
BR